# C# multi-hop SSH (SSH through SSH)

Tags: c#, linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I wrote a C# console program to connect from A (Windows 10, Console C# app) over SSH to B (Linux server) and from there on to C (Linux server), but I cannot connect from B to C (from A to B is ok).
When I connect from A over Windows terminal to B and from B's terminal to C, it works, so I proved that my credentials are fine.

- I am using Renci.SshNet for C#
- I created a class `Server` with a `.Connect()`, `.Disconnect()` and `.Execute()` extension methods and then the two class instances `Broker` and `Destination`
- My code looks like:

  ```
   if (Broker.Connect())
   {
     Broker.Execute("pwd");

     if (Destination.Connect())
     {
        Destination.Execute("pwd");
        Destination.Disconnect();
     }
     Broker.Disconnect();
   }
  ```
- The `Ssh` connection objets are created like `var broker = new SftpClient("Ip", Port, "User", "Pass")`
- Then I am internally using `broker.Connect()` and `broker.Disconnect()` in `Renci.Ssh.Net` lib given methods
- To `broker.Execute("cmd")` I basically do

  ```
  var output = host.Ssh.RunCommand(str);
  var res0 = output.ExitStatus;
  var res1 = output.Result;
  var res2 = output.Error;
  ```
- My code works for the first part as I manage to get the output of `Broker.Execute("pwd")` but it does not connect on `Destination.Connect()` returning the message `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`
- My aim ist to multi-hop using an automated process from within C#: users **must not** interact with any console and I **cannot** modify nor store any files on the Linux sites

Any idea where the problem lies?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This is pretty vague. Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code from your program and describe exactly what happens when you run it. Include any error messages and stacktraces that you get.

Comment: Please try `ssh userc@hostc -J userB@hostb`  on your host-a. If that works, you can add a host into your `.ssh/config` file

Comment: `Destination.Connect` will probably try to connect from hostA to HostC directly, I don't believe it will use host-B for that

Comment: @jeb for using `ssh userc@hostc -J userB@hostb` ... where do i give in the passwords? for `Destination.Connect` yes, that is exactly my guess as well... but i don't know/find how to solve it...

Comment: Just use `ssh` from the command line, it will ask for the passwords. And then *avoid passwords use keys instead*

Comment: @jeb My aim ist to multi-hop using an automated process from within C#: users must not interact with any console and I cannot modify nor store any files on the Linux sites

Comment: The `ssh userc@hostc ...` was only to test the connection not for your C# code. But if that works, you should be able to use a .ssh/config entry to solve your problem

Comment: `var broker = new SftpClient(...` looks like you are creating a sftp connection instead of a ssh one. `pwd` works because it's also a valid command for ftp, better try something like `hostname`

Comment: @jeb oh sorry, that was a copy-paste failure because I was testing ssh and sfpt; my code is correctly using `var broker = new SshClient(...)`

Comment: @jeb I cannot modify the `.ssh/config` of the `B` and `C` servers

Comment: You don't need to modify .ssh/config on `B` or `C`, but does the `ssh userc@hostc -J userB@hostb` work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238357/discussion-between-jeb-and-paul-efford).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will like to summarize here how I ended solving this issue with the help of some valuable hints gathered over the net and from @jeb:

Open a cmd.exe console, type `ssh userC@hostC -p portC-J userB@hostB - p portB` (`portB` and `portC` can be ommited if they are the default port 22) and then you will be promped to enter `passwordB` and `passwordC` - in this order.
If the connection succeeded you will be then on the `hostC` console and will manage to do whatever you intend to do.

The code you'll need is:

```
static void RunSshHop(params string[] cmds)
{
    try
    {
        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
            {
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                //WorkingDirectory = @"d:\" // dir of your "cmd.exe"
            };

            p.OutputDataReceived += p_DataReceived;
            p.ErrorDataReceived += p_DataReceived;

            p.Start();

            // way 1: works
            foreach (var e in cmds)
                p.StandardInput.Write($"{e}\n"); // cannot use 'WriteLine' because Windows is '\r' and Linux is '\n'

            /* way 2: works as well
            using (var sw = p.StandardInput)
            {
                foreach (var e in cmds)
                    if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                        sw.Write($"{e}\n"); // cannot use 'WriteLine' because Windows is '\r' and Linux is '\n'
            }
            //*/

            p.WaitForExit();

            if (p.HasExited)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ExitCode: {p.ExitCode}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunSshHop(
       "ssh userC@hostC -p portC-J userB@hostB - p portB",
       "pwd",
       //"...",
       "ls"
    );
}
```

To avoid having to enter the passwords for each host, you can also create an SSH key pair like this:

- open `cmd.exe` console
- type `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
- choose path where to save the public and private keys that are to be generated (press `enter` to use the default destination)
- copy the destination, you will need it later to get back yxour keys :-)
- to manage an automated process, you have to leave the `passphrase` empty
  -once the keys are generated, log onto the first host over ssh like `ssh youruser@firsthost -p hostport` (the `-p hostport` part can be ignored if port is the default `22`)
- type `ssh-copy-id youruser@firsthost -p hostport`
- accept
- repeat the process for the second host